# @storybook/addon-controls: howto not auto-generate control for a certain prop

Tags: reactjs, storybook

`@storybook/addon-controls` is fun, however I cannot find a way to disable control generation for a given arg. Lets say I have a component prop that is an event handler and I obviously do not want it to have a control. So I want it to appear in the list of props with the name, type and description, but no control. How do I do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

this was recently added: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/pull/11388
Essentially you should be able to use `control.disable` within `argTypes` for a given arg.

Suppose you have a story with `foo` and `bar` properties (auto-generated or otherwise) and you want to hide the `foo` row completely and disable controls for the `bar` row on a specific story:

```
MyStory.argTypes = {
  foo: { table: { disable: true } },
  bar: { control: { disable: true } },
};
```

Here's the entry in the [docs](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/next/addons/controls#how-can-i-disable-controls-for-certain-fields-on-a-particular-story).

Cheers

Comment: Maybe update it with an actual example, not just link external resources - links may break in future, but your answer should stay self-sustainable.

Comment: Even after the above change, It seems there is no way to show arg in controls, but hide it in the table

Comment: What's the difference between `{table: {disable: true}}` and `{control: {disable: true}}`

Answer (score 8):

About a year ago include and exclude of args was added ([link to the PR](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/pull/13898)).

In the [documentation](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls#filtering-controls) it is referred to as "Filtering Controls".

You can choose which arguments to include and/or exclude by string, array or regular expression.

##### Usage example (from the docs):

```
const Template = (args) => ({
    // Your template goes here
});

ArrayInclude = Template.bind({})
ArrayInclude.parameters = { controls: { include: ['foo', 'bar'] } };

RegexInclude = Template.bind({})
RegexInclude.parameters = { controls: { include: /^hello*/ } };

ArrayExclude = Template.bind({})
ArrayExclude.parameters = { controls: { exclude: ['foo', 'bar'] } };

RegexExclude = Template.bind({})
RegexExclude.parameters = { controls: { exclude: /^hello*/ } };
```